# How to wrap a HTML-tag around a specific text

Tags: jquery, html, regex

How do I change this

```
var html = '<div>doe, john (Likes pizza)</div>'
```

To this:

```
var result = '<div>doe, john <span class="myspan">(Likes pizza)</span></div>'
```

to find the parens `(...)` and wrap it with a `<span>`

Comment: You should not stuff the title with tags and leave the tags to a minimum, please modify the header and tags and clarify the question qua language framework etc....

Comment: @Casper is saying make the title more meaningful and put the language and library information in the tags for your question.

Comment: Also, look up `indexOf` and you should have what you need to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the console of Chromium:

```
>> re = new RegExp(/\((.+)\)/);

>> s = "<div>doe, john (Likes pizza)</div>";
"<div>doe, john (Likes pizza)</div>"
>> s.replace(re, "<span class=\"myspan\">($1)</span>");
"<div>doe, john <span class="myspan">(Likes pizza)</span></div>"

>> ss2 = "<div>doe, john (Likes football)</div>";
"<div>doe, john (Likes football)</div>"
>> ss2.replace(re, "<span class=\"myspan\">($1)</span>");
"<div>doe, john <span class="myspan">(Likes football)</span></div>"
```

Edit - so that it finds any text inside parens, and not just "Likes pizza".

Edit2 - as described in the comments, it can be broken, e.g. with `s = "<div class="Eric (likes breaking things)"> >>doe, john ((Likes) nested regex)</div>";`

Comment: the text inside the parens can vary. that is why i need a regex match.

Comment: I broke it: `<div class="Eric (likes breaking things)">doe, john (Likes pizza)</div>`

Comment: @Eric - but then it failed with nested parentheses - so deciding to leave it as it is, with a warning about your case.

Comment: @aeter: Of course, the lesson to be learnt here is not to parse HTML with regex!

Answer (score 1):

This will handle your example:

```
"<div>doe, john (Likes pizza)</div>".replace(/(\([^)]*\))/g,
            "<span class=\"myclass\">$1</span>")
```

It will capture anything between an open parenthesis and the next close paren, and uses a backreference to reinsert it with the `<span>` around it.

Comment: what happens with a nested parenthesis?

Comment: @corroded: Bad things =p
In general, regexes aren't powerful enough to handle matching parentheses to arbitrary nested depths. But I assumed in this case it was overkill for me to even protect against more than one set of parentheses on a line (not nested), so I just thought I'd split the difference and explain the matching logic exactly.

Comment: @corroded: yes, I'm known throughout the land (at my workplace, anyway) for my robust/anal regexes.